# Why does this code not add another field when clicking on the `add another field` input button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why does [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/fbzvX/) not add another text input field when clicking on the `add another field` input button?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function add_field() 
{
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.setAttribute('type','text');
elem.setAttribute('name','user');
document.body.insertBefore(elem, document.getElementById('su'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="input" method="get">
Put input here:<br> 
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="button" onclick="add_field()" value="Add another field"><br>
<input id="su" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore), you need to call `parent.insertBefore(newElem, referenceElem)`. In your example, I suppose that `<form>` is the parent, not `<body>`. Changing the last line of your function to this:

```
var target = document.getElementById('su');
target.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, target);
```

will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/fbzvX/3/)

```
<form name="input" method="get">
  Put input here:<br> 
  <input id='ap' type="text" name="user">
  <input id="addField" type="button" value="Add another field"><br>
  <input id="su" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#addField').click(function(e)
{
    $('<input type="text" />').insertBefore('#su')
});​​
```